# Python Pandas: Forward Fill with Arithmetic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have the following DataFrame:

```
            AAPL shares  GOOG shares  MSFT shares
date                                             
2019-01-01          NaN         10.0          NaN
2019-01-05          NaN          NaN         15.0
2019-01-12          NaN          NaN          7.0
2019-01-13          3.0          NaN          NaN
2019-01-14          NaN         -5.0          NaN
```

After applying a forward fill:

`print(df.set_index('date').sort_index().fillna(method='ffill').fillna(value=0))`

I get:

```
            AAPL shares  GOOG shares  MSFT shares
date                                             
2019-01-01          0.0         10.0          0.0
2019-01-05          0.0         10.0         15.0
2019-01-12          0.0         10.0          7.0
2019-01-13          3.0         10.0          7.0
2019-01-14          3.0         -5.0          7.0
```

My question is there any way to fill forward with simple addition? The result I'm looking for:

```
            AAPL shares  GOOG shares  MSFT shares
date                                             
2019-01-01          0.0         10.0          0.0
2019-01-05          0.0         10.0         15.0
2019-01-12          0.0         10.0         22.0
2019-01-13          3.0         10.0         22.0
2019-01-14          3.0          5.0         22.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with `cumsum`

```
df.fillna(0).cumsum()
            AAPLshares  GOOGshares  MSFTshares
date                                          
2019-01-01         0.0        10.0         0.0
2019-01-05         0.0        10.0        15.0
2019-01-12         0.0        10.0        22.0
2019-01-13         3.0        10.0        22.0
2019-01-14         3.0         5.0        22.0
```

Comment: Ohhh I misinterpreted your answer at first, looks like it works!! Will accept your answer in 4 minutes lol thank you